# Good settings for typesetting source code with wide lines?

Tags: sourcecode

I'd like to typeset some source code with [minted](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted?lang=en). Unfortunately, a lot this source code runs over 80 columns, some of it up to 132.

What are good settings (and open source fonts?) to use with minted so that I can avoid as much line wrapping as possible?

Comment: There's no technical solution to 'my text is too wide': usually this comes up with tables, but it's the same for source code. You'll have to make a human judgement about where line's can be altered.